# Describing protagonist's experience from using magic

Tags: creative-writing, technique

I am writing a fanfic where the protagonist is a skeleton living on Earth. He possesses a magic skill which revolves around moving objects. Of course, there are limits. He cannot move things as heavy as a tower. Although the limit point isn't very clear, (I am not planning on establishing it either), it'd be good to assume that he cannot exactly magically move anything that has more mass than him. His other notable skill is the ability to teleport, but this once again does not have an established limit.

In any case, the protagonist is to use his magic to move simple objects around during the story, such as lifting a piece of ribbon in air, maybe even a medium-sized box. One of my goals is to capture the sense of what the magic user goes through in order to make the reader more familiar and comfortable with the theme of magic. What are some of the ways I could approach this kind of magic experience?

Comment: Hi Tanya! It's not entirely clear to me what it is you're having difficulty with here. You say you want to _capture the sense of what the magic user goes through_ , great -- can you go ahead and, well, describe what he feels and what the experience is like for him? What is it that's giving you trouble here?

Comment: I should point out that we try to avoid ["what to write" questions](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/136/is-a-help-me-generate-plot-ideas-or-similar-question-on-topic) here - they don't have any one answer, and they aren't helpful to others. So we're looking for something beyond "I need to write X; how should I do that" -- be specific, tell us why this specific thing is difficult for you.

Comment: User hasn't edited or even replied to mod comments. I'm placing on hold until this question is edited and improved.

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt a backstory for the character in a chapter. I wouldn't go for expalining the magical aspect too much, but rather explain the way he solves his problems with his ability and how he overcomes the limitations of the same. It also depends if you're going for "Hard Magic" or "Soft magic" or somewhere in between. Think if you want to approach your story with magic being more mysterious or more all-out and visible. Soft magic needs scarcely be explained, whereas Hard magic needs a little more explaining since it's so obvious and it affects the course of the story in a stronger way. Hope this helps.